How do I put colored text boxes in latex? (In math environment)
I am trying to do something like in the picture attached, if someone knows how to please let me know. The goal is to draw two boxes around two terms of this equation in two different colors. I don't mind if its an ellipse shape or a box with rounded corners, just wouldn't want a box with sharp corners.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code what you tried so far,

Or search the site for tikzmark.

Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz

Another option is tcolorbox.

With handwriting like that, who needs TeX? :-)

I think the best option for you will be tcolorbox. Start with my example below.
Other options could be tikzmark along with tikz or a simple macro \fcolorbox from xcolor but the latter draws just squared boxes.
Here's the example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\NewDocumentCommand\xfbox{sO{black}m}{%
   \tcboxmath[
        size=fbox,
        arc=1.25mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=#2,
    ]{\IfBooleanF{#1}{\vphantom{X}}#3}} 

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x) =
    \xfbox[Red]{ax^2 + bx}
    + \xfbox[Blue]{c}
    + \xfbox{D}
    + \xfbox*[Green]{e}.
\]
\end{document}

EDIT. The \tcboxmath from tcolorbox and the library theorems accepts plenty of arguments, so I enclosed it in a macro to simplify code. The non-starred version will draw boxes of minimum size, while the starred version draws a tight box around its content.


With pure TikZ:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{mwe}% <-- for testing purpose only

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\newcommand{\fromhere}[3]{\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=#1, shape=ellipse, inner xsep=-1pt, inner ysep=2pt, outer sep=0pt] (#2) {#3};}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only
\[
\mathrm{D}_{\overline{\mathrm{PLT}}}-
\fromhere{orange}{f1}{$\mu_{\mathrm{D}_{\overline{\mathrm{PLT}}}}$}+
\fromhere{green}{f2}{$Z(SL)-\sigma_{\mathrm{D}_{\overline{\mathrm{PLT}}}}$}
\]\vspace{1.8cm}% necessary to leave to space for the overlay

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \node[orange, below left =.4cm of f1, text width=4cm, align=flush center] (d1) {quantity belongs to operating conditions (OPERATING SHOCKS)};
  \draw[->, orange] (f1) -- (d1); 
  \node[green, below right=.5cm and -.2cm of f2, text width=4cm, align=flush center] (d2) {SAFETY STOCK: quantity that etc.};
  \draw[->, green] (f2) -- (d2.160); 
  \draw ([xshift=3mm]f2.west) to[out=-90, in=-110] coordinate(f3) ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1.5mm]f2.center);
  \node[below=1cm of f3, text width=2cm, align=flush center] (d3) {function of service level};
  \draw[->] (f3) -- (d3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only
\end{document}


